# Why is it not safe to use Socket.ReceiveLength?

Tags: delphi, winsock

Well, even [Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TCustomWinSocket.ReceiveLength) states that it is not guaranteed to return accurate result of the bytes ready to read in the socket buffer, but if you look at it, when you place -1 at Socket.ReceiveBuf (this is what ReceiveLength wraps) it calls **ioctlsocket** with **FIONREAD** *to determine the amount of data pending in the network's input buffer that can be read from socket s*.

so, how is it not safe or bad ?

e.g: `ioctlsocket(Socket.SocketHandle, FIONREAD, Longint(i));`

Comment: It would be nice if you include a link to where Embarcadero (or any other party) states what you say.

Comment: @jachguate: I supplied the link. It's from `TCustomWinSocket`, and is actually present at least as far back as D2007.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation you mention specifically says (emphasis mine)

> Note: ReceiveLength is not guaranteed to be accurate **for streaming socket connections**.

This means that the length is not known ahead of time because it's being supplied by a stream of data. Obviously, if you don't know how big the data is that's being sent ahead of time, you can't properly set the length the client should expect.

Consider it like generic code to copy a file. If you don't know ahead of time how big the file is you'll be copying, you can't predict how many bytes you'll be copying. In the case of the socket, the stream size that's supplying the socket isn't known in advance (for instance, for data being generated real-time and sent), so there's no way to inform the client socket how much to expect.

Comment: That's very true what you said, i could send 8 bytes, and ReceiveLength will see only 4 bytes, and after that get another 4 bytes.